# highlight datatable search string

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have used datatables to display database table records. Here i have to highlight the search string. I google it and found the following link.

[jQuery plugin DataTables: How to highlight the current search text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644975/jquery-plugin-datatables-how-to-highlight-the-current-search-text)

In my case it is not working. May be because i use ajax method to load the data.

```
"sAjaxSource": "test.php"
```

Please let me know, how to implement this. Thanks

Comment: **There's now a new plugin to handle search highlighting for DataTables: [datatables.mark.js](https://github.com/julmot/datatables.mark.js).**

Answer (score 0):

I've try the highlight JQuery plugin with dynamic content and it works fine : http://goo.gl/kezH0o

So I need more information of your problem to help you (some code maybe ?)

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
    <div id="results"><h1>Search for: Lorem ipsum, it will be highligted.</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>One Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Two Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Just Lorem</li>
    <li>None of it</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

css:

```
    .highlight { background-color: yellow }
```

javascript:

```
    var search = "Lorem ipsum";

    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {
        search: search,
        delay: 1
    },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function() {
        $('#results ul').highlight(search);
    });
```

Comment: I am using https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html method