# How to highlight searchtext records in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Name                  Role

```
applicationame          role                     id
application1           appadministrator      1490
application            developer             1498
application2            tester               1460
```

I need the result like if entered 'app' as searchtext need to highlight all rows ,because all rows are having app.if entereted 'application' as searchtext then need to highlight 2nd row only. because exact macth.like that i need to check all columns i.e aplication,role etc.
no need of hide the unmacthed rows.need to highlight matching only if not macth just display as it is.

if user entered '14' as searchtext need to highlight all rows.if he entered 1490 need to highlight 1strow and display remaining rows as it is.please help me to achieve this.

My fidler:   http://jsfiddle.net/kUxNj/4/

Please modify my fidler according this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644975/jquery-plugin-datatables-how-to-highlight-the-current-search-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase() === text.toUpperCase() ||
                    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase() === text.toUpperCase()
                   )
```

With this:

```
if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) != -1 ||
                    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().indexOf(text.toUpperCase()) != -1
                   )
```

How it works: your code looks whether the given text is *equal* to one of the rows, but my code checks whether one of the rows *contains* the given text, using the [`indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2FindexOf).

And to avoid hiding of non-matching elements, remove the following code:

```
if(grid.find('td.result').length >0){
                grid.find('td').not('.result').parent('tr').hide();
            }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUxNj/7/

Comment: no need to hide the non matching records.if matching should apply color ,not macthing as it is display other records.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `match()` method instead of the equality check:

```
if ($(this).find('td:first-child').text().toUpperCase().match( text.toUpperCase()) ||
    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toUpperCase().match( text.toUpperCase())) 
{
    $(this).children('td').addClass('result');
}
```

I also removed the `hide()` and `show()` calls as they are redundant to highlighting rows like you ask.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUxNj/9/