# jQuery plugin DataTables: How to reference Search textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to implement the solution here:

[jQuery plugin DataTables: How to highlight the current search text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644975/jquery-plugin-datatables-how-to-highlight-the-current-search-text)

But I can't seem to reference the Search field properly:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" aria-controls="tblMainHorz">
```

I tried the following:

```
$("#tblMainHorz").highlight($("input.form-control input-sm").val());
$("#tblMainHorz").highlight($("input.form-control.input-sm").val());
$("#tblMainHorz").highlight($("input.form-control\\.input-sm").val());
```

But none of them are working.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('.dataTables_filter > label > input').val('xxx')` - works for me...

Comment: I tried both:
    $("#tblMainHorz").highlight($('.tblMainHorz_filter input').val());
    $("#tblMainHorz").highlight($('#tblMainHorz_filter input').val());

Also tried:

    $("#tblMainHorz").highlight($('#dataTables_filter input').val());

But I know that's not what my table is called (dataTables).  Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK, the .dataTables_filter is a generic class applied by dataTables, so I expected it to work w/o changes on your page, too.
It is assigned to the div that contains the filter - aaahh, but maybe that's the problem, it was sufficient for my case to get that surrounding div, whereas you need to get to the input directly. Just a moment, I'll update my code :)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried $("#tblMainHorz").highlight($('.dataTables_filter > label > input').val()); -- still doesn't work...

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle perhaps? (Www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: FYI, this is what the section looks like:

<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
    <div class="dataTables_filter" id="tblMainHorz_filter">
      <label>
        Find<input class="form-control input-sm" aria-controls="tblMainHorz" type="search">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual html after dataTables was applied? Because if that was all, then it would work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/k8FRy/5/  So something must be different in your setup...

Comment: Here's a fiddle which uses dataTables, so it should be matching your sitation: http://jsfiddle.net/vXq7U/1/