# Highlight search text jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to highlight matching **texts** (not rows) in the jquery datatable when searching. The question is duplicate, but I tried the answers with no success.
I tried,

```
 $('.dataTables_filter input').keyup(function () {
        $('#table td').removeHighlight();
        if ($('.dataTables_filter input').val() != "") {
            $('#table td').highlight($('.dataTables_filter input').val());
        }
    });
```

It works great but when the table redraws (when the text inside input changes),  the hightlight is removed (it makes sense, but can't fix). 
[Tried this too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644975/jquery-plugin-datatables-how-to-highlight-the-current-search-text)

Comment: **There's now a new plugin to handle search highlighting for DataTables: [datatables.mark.js](https://github.com/julmot/datatables.mark.js).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with datatable callback or event function:

```
var yourTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    yourTable.on( 'stateLoaded.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
        if ($('.dataTables_filter input').val() != "") {
            $('#table td').highlight($('.dataTables_filter input').val());
        }
} );
```

http://datatables.net/reference/event/stateLoaded

or

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "stateSave": true,
  "stateLoaded": function (settings, data) {
     if ($('.dataTables_filter input').val() != "") {
        $('#table td').highlight($('.dataTables_filter input').val());
     }
  }
} );
```

http://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoaded

i haven't use this specific plugin but as you can see in the api you have callback function that can be used.

Comment: drawCallback worked.

`"drawCallback": function (settings) {
                if ($('.dataTables_filter input').val() != "") {
                    $('#table td').highlight($('.dataTables_filter input').val());
                }
            }`

Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Perfect,
i read it but it seems from the description that it trigger before the draw so i don't insert in the example

Comment: @MikeDebela I am having issues with your implementation, my error is `$(...).highlight is not a function`, even after including jquery UI. any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @NoamHacker I think you need jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: @MikeDebela, thanks for the quick reply. it looks like I already have that :/

Comment: @NoamHacker Ohh... sorry I used this one jquery.highlight-5.js

Comment: @MikeDebela thanks again! after implementing this I no longer have the error, but nothing is appearing to be getting highlighted. did you run into a similar problem?

Comment: actually, it worked after adding `.highlight { background-color: yellow }`. good luck with your future endeavours :)