# How to make highlight.js work in several dataTables in one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, highlight

So far [highlight.js](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) works fine highlighting the text you are looking for inside a Datatable. However, if I use more than one dataTable in the same page, the highlight.js only works fine for the first one.

My three tables look like this (in summary):

1:

```
<table class="table table-hover display" id="table_m">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
```

2:

```
<table class="table table-hover display" id="table_r">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
```

3:

```
<table class="table table-hover display" id="table_a">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
```

Here is the jQuery code that activates the three dataTables in one page:

```
var table = $('table.display').DataTable();     
   table.on( 'draw', function () {     
    var body = $( table.table().body() );          
    body.unhighlight();         
    body.highlight( table.search() );     
} );
```

And, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2644997/1883256) I use the following below that code:

```
$("table.display").highlight($("#searchBox").val());
```

And I have tried to find out where the #searchBox id comes from with no luck. I didn't find it neither in the dataTables.js nor in the highlight.js. I have even noticed that the highlighting still works without that id (but only for the first table):

```
$("table.display").highlight();
```

How can I tell highlight to work in the three tables? How do I specify the ID's of the search inputs of the different dataTables? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the answer you provided, `#searchBox` merely provides a handle for the data being searched for. Replace `$("#searchBox").val()` with a reference to the chunk of data you wish to highlight.

In other words, if you want to highlight the word `foo` in your tables, and you have a text input with an id of `#myInput` that contains the value `foo`, replace `$("#searchBox").val()` with `$("#myInput").val()`.

Alternatively, you could hard-code the value like so:

`$("table.display").highlight("foo");`

If you have 3 different search inputs (one for each table), make sure you give them each a unique id and try calling `highlight()` on each table individually:

```
$("#table_m").highlight($("#searchBox_m").val());
$("#table_r").highlight($("#searchBox_r").val());
$("#table_a").highlight($("#searchBox_a").val());
```

Comment: How can I tell highlight to work in the three tables? How do I specify the ID's of the search inputs of the different dataTables?

Comment: I have now adjusted my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: If it didn't work, please let me know. If it did, please select my answer as valid. Thank you!

Comment: I have tried them and still works the same :/ Only the first table is highlighted when you search for a value. Nevertheless `$("table.display").highlight("foo");` works in the three tables...

Comment: Do you have three inputs with the ids of "searchbox_m/r/a"? Because if you type "foo" into a textbox with an id (not name) of "searchbox_m", then `$("#searchBox_m").val()` == `"foo"`, and therefore, `$("#table_m").highlight($("#searchBox_a").val());` == `$("#table_m").highlight("foo");`

Comment: Also, make sure you give each table a unique ID and call .highlight() once at a time (call it three times). Don't use `table.display`. Use `#table_m`, `"#table_r"`, and `#table_a`.