# How to highlight filtered text of DataTable using jQuery plug-in?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I started working with **DataTable** plug-in, for filtering the result and pagination. However I want to scan the results in order to locate the specific data any user search for, using **jQuery** plug-in for **highlighting** **text**.
In short, I want to use search result highlight plug-in for DataTable using jQuery.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A jQuery plugin has been created for this purpose. It is documented on their website.  https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22

Comment: **There's now a new plugin to handle search highlighting for DataTables: [datatables.mark.js](https://github.com/julmot/datatables.mark.js).**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery plugin DataTables: How to highlight the current search text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644975/jquery-plugin-datatables-how-to-highlight-the-current-search-text)

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Jquery Datatable? If yes, then try like this,

Download and include CSS and JS files:

```
dataTables.searchHighlight.css
dataTables.searchHighlight.js
```

Which can be download from following Github: https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/features/searchHighlight

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();

    table.on( 'draw', function () {
        var body = $( table.table().body() );

        body.unhighlight();
        body.highlight( table.search() );  
    } );
} );
```

Follow this link for more info:
https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-22

Comment: Yes, I am using Jquery DataTable. But is there any requirement of Jquery highlight plug-in for DataTable to execute this code?

Comment: Yes, you may need searchHighlight.css and dataTables.searchHighlight.js; which can be downloaded from following git hub:  https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/features/searchHighlight

Comment: I guess this would work if you display more than one table in one page ... I will test this later ...