# Highlight search text bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, search, highlight

I'm trying to implement [**jquery plugin**](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) for highlighting search text to my app and I'm using [**this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644975/jquery-plugin-datatables-how-to-highlight-the-current-search-text), I've put jquery plugin to my app and add this line:

```
  $table.highlight($(".search.bs.table").val());
```

But searching text still doesn't highlighting. Somebody could me explain, Where is my mistake?

[**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/cm4bKF8DNFHnSRCMOPJr?p=preview)

code:

```
function initTable() {
    $table.bootstrapTable({
        filterControl: true,
        //data: url,
        //url: 'data/events.json',
        height: getHeight(),
        formatNoMatches: function () {
            return "Please, choose your category";
        }

    });

    // sometimes footer render error.
    setTimeout(function () {
        $table.bootstrapTable('resetView');
    }, 200);
    $table.on('check.bs.table uncheck.bs.table ' +
        'check-all.bs.table uncheck-all.bs.table', function () {
        $remove.prop('disabled', !$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections').length);
        // save your data, here just save the current page
        selections = getIdSelections();
        // push or splice the selections if you want to save all data selections
    });
    $table.on('all.bs.table', function (e, name, args) {
        console.log(name, args);
    });
    $table.highlight($(".search.bs.table").val());

    $table.on('search.bs.table', function (e, text){

        "use strict";
        console.log(e);
        console.log(text);
    });
    $remove.click(function () {
        var ids = getIdSelections();
        $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
            field: 'id',
            values: ids
        });
        $remove.prop('disabled', true);
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $table.bootstrapTable('resetView', {
            //height: getHeight()
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out, how it works
Below the right code (put this code inside inittable):

```
$table.highlight($(".search.bs.table").val());

$table.on('search.bs.table', function (e, text){

    $table.highlight(text);
    console.log(e);
    console.log(text);
});
```

css:

```
.highlight {background-color: yellow}
```

Comment: I notice you ask an issue before, and if anyone wants a reference, you can click this [link-bootstrap-table-issue-2172](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/2172#issuecomment-211533869).

Answer (score 1):

for version >= 1.18.x you can use [data-search-highlight](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/#searchhighlight)

```html
<table data-search-highlight="true"></table>
```

[example code](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/d4dc885d6cd925a591cec11674ffa6a06438dc1c/options/search-highlight.html#L14)